# string operations on a string that contains html

Tags: php, html, string, dom, replace

In PHP, I'm getting an API call response like this and I save this in a string variable ***$var*** with the value given below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <title>some title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="../logo.png" />
    <p>My Page</p>
</body>
```

why I'm not able to do the following?

```
str_replace("My Page", "My HTML page", $var);
```

also

```
str_replace("../", "http://example.com/", $var);
```

1) Can I perform simple string operations on a string that contain html?

2) How can I change the ***src*** attribute in script tag in head.

Comment: are you actually assigning the result of the replace? ie. `$var = str_replace($search, $replace, $var)`

Comment: You're going to have to show us more of your PHP code. Nothing is obviously wrong with anything you've shown us.

Comment: A string that contains HTML tags is still just a string to PHP; it doesn't discriminate on the grounds of race, gender, religion, sexual orientation or markup

Comment: Although if you want to manipulate markup, use Dom

Comment: @billyonecan Yes you are right. This is the mistake i made

Comment: @MarkBaker ok, I can also use HTML parser

Comment: Yes I just miss a simple trick @Brogan thanks